# Creating an equation from a group of numbers and the answer

Tags: number-theory, fractions

*sigh*... I've been trying for three days to figure out this one last question.
Any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

The objective is to create an equation/formula with the given information of the numbers it consists of and the answer.
The equation/formula must be applicable to all four groups of information.

No. 20 is the only other question with fractions so I added it as an example.
No. 20's answer is the numerator(n) divided by the denominator(d) with the decimals removed.

Questions:

20. numbers  answers

    1/3        -    0

    2/3        -    0

    3/3        -    1

    4/5        -    0

    equation
        n ÷ d = a, 
        then remove decimals
    e.g.

    ```
    1 ÷ 3 = 0.3333333333 = 0
    2 ÷ 3 = 0.6666666667 = 0
    3 ÷ 3 = 1
    4 ÷ 5 = 0.8 = 0
    ```
21. numbers answers

    2/3,
      5/5       -    2

    2/3,
      4/5       -    0

    2/2,
      2/3       -    3

    1/2,
      3/3       -    2

    equation
    ?

Comment: Seems like in the first question (question 20) you just have to take the floor function of the input value. But question 21 is trickier since the value can decrease: $f(2/3) = 3$ but $f(3/3) = 2$. Am I interpreting it correctly?

Comment: I didn't know about the floor function thanks. The combination of $2/2 & 2/3 = 3$, and $1/2 & 3/3 = 2$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Matti i think for the second problem he wants a two variable function. e.g. $f(2/3, 5/5) = 2$.

Comment: I think the easy way out is to define the function $f(x, y)$ as follows: $f(2/3, 5/5) = 2, f(2/3, 4/5) = 0, f(2/2, 2/3) = 2, f(1/2, 3/3) = 3, f(x, y) = 0$ for all other $x, y$. Now $f$ clearly satisfies each equation.